# Augmentation of the sphere spectrum

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I am wondering if it is sensible to talk about the augmentation ideal of the sphere spectrum in the category of spectra, as well as the `submodule of decomposables', whose construction comes from the algebra of the spectrum, so that the homotopy groups of the submodule of decomposable elements coincides with the submodule of decomposable elements inside $\pi_*^s$. In particular, I like to concentrate at the prime $p=2$. I believe this would be different from simply taking $\{S^n:n>0\}$ as the augmentation.

Let me explain. For an graded algebra $A$ over a field $k$, with $A_i=0$ for $i<0$, together with an augmentation $\epsilon:A\to k$, one defines $IA=\mathrm{ker}(\epsilon)$, and then the submodule of decomposables is the image of $IA\otimes IA\to A$. I wonder if such a formulation exists!? Since, I don't know of a ring object on which $S^0$ is an augmented algebra, I then fail to proceed with the analogous construction.

Comment: Couldn't you simply regard the unit map $S\to E$ of some ring spectrum $E$, e.g. an Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectrum, as an augmentation in your sense, and embed this map in a fibration sequence? If you take $E=K(\mathbb Z,\cdot)$ for example, this will kill $\pi_0^s$ and leave only the higher stable homotopy groups.

Comment: The notion of cotangent complex for ring spectra has been worked out. The first published account that I am aware of is due to Maria Basterra and is a really excellent article. You should note that you have to derive your functors each step of the way. This means that you don't end up with something like $\pi_*Q(S)=Q(\pi_(S)$. Also, $S^0$ is initial, so it can only be an augmented algebra over itself.

Comment: @SeanTilson why a cotagent complex is related to an augmentation?!

Comment: @SebastianGoette Maybe I expect too much, and just a ring map such as you quote is enough!

Comment: An augmentation in algebra is the same as a point in a scheme. Then you can try to take the "tangent space" at that point. It turns out that this is not as simple when your point is not smooth (I guess that is a bit obvious, no?) and you get a tangent complex. Anytime you want to compute a cotangent complex you need a point to compute it at. I suggest you look into this stuff as what you are describing as your goal is literally on its way to Kahler 1-forms.

Comment: @SeanTilson I think for the moment, the suggestion of Sebastian Goette is of use in my purpose. I didn't have Kahler forms in mind, and I wonder how you see that I am going in that direction. Later on, I remembered that, in agreement with Goette's suggestion, previously people have used maps into Eilenberg-Moore spectra to obtain augmentations of the sphere spectrum which seems suitable for the purposes that I have in mind, e.g. Kuhn and Priddy's paper on the Whitehead conjecture.

Comment: In case you change your mind, there is a nice paper by Iyengar on the cotangent complex in commutative algebra. I agree that there are definitely maps from the sphere spectrum to Eilenberg-MacLane spectra, you can certainly use these.